# Get carbon to work with laravel's updated_at column in users table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, php-carbon

I have a datatables that i created using laravel and this is the code i am using to fetch the data

```
public function getTasks()
    {
      $users = User::select(['id','users_full_names', 'email', 'users_telephone_number', 'users_credits', 'users_last_seen_carbon_object','users_profile_picture','updated_at']);

        return Datatables::of($users)
            ->addColumn('action', function ($user) {
                return '<a href="/edit/'.$user->id.'" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit</a> <a href="/delete/'.$user->id.'" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</a> <a href="/moderate/'.$user->emp_no.'" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i> Moderate</a> <a href="/view/'.$user->emp_no.'" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> View</a> <a href="/impersonate/'.$user->id.'" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Impersonate</a>';
            })->editColumn('users_last_seen_carbon_object', function(User $user) {
               $datetime = Carbon::createFromDate($user->updated_at);
                    return $datetime->diffForHumans();
                })->make(true);
    }
```

Sample data contained in updated_at column look like this

`2017-05-06 15:16:54`

Earlier on i tried `return $user->updated_at->diffForHumans()` but the json was corrupt.

This code

```
$datetime = Carbon::createFromDate($user->updated_at);
return $datetime->diffForHumans();
```

displays last_seen 1 second ago for all rows and does not update even after a duration.

How can i ensure last seen displays as it should?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The updated_at field should be an instance of Carbon and using the method `diffForHumans` on it should work just fine.

```
return $user->updated_at->diffForHumans();
```

Can I know how is that corrupting your json response? Also you don't need to specify the model type in this code.

```
function(User $user)
```

Comment: return $user->updated_at->toDateTimeString()->diffForHumans(\Carbon\Carbon::now()); gives a syntax error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'diffForHumans' (T_STRING), expecting ';'`

Comment: That won't work since you're converting the Carbon instance to a string. Why don't you try `return $user->updated_at->diffForHumans();` and show me what errors you get if any.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working this way

```
public function getTasks()
    {
      $users = User::select(['id','users_full_names', 'email', 'users_telephone_number', 'users_credits', 'users_last_seen_carbon_object','users_profile_picture','updated_at']);

        return Datatables::of($users)
            ->addColumn('action', function ($user) {
                return '<a href="/edit/'.$user->id.'" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit</a> <a href="/delete/'.$user->id.'" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</a> <a href="/moderate/'.$user->emp_no.'" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i> Moderate</a> <a href="/view/'.$user->emp_no.'" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> View</a> <a href="/impersonate/'.$user->id.'" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Impersonate</a>';
            })->editColumn('updated_at', function(User $user) {
              $dt = $user->updated_at->toDateTimeString();
              $datetime = Carbon::parse($dt);;
                    return $datetime->diffForHumans();
                })->make(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Only use `$user->updated_at` without `Carbon::createFromDate($user->updated_at)`, because the `updated_at`  is a `date_format`. You don't need the `Carbon::createFromDate`.

if you want `$date = $user->updated_at`

and after:

```
return $date->diffForHumans();
```

Comment: please format the code with the backtick (\`) for ease of reading